# Why can't we increase quantum entanglement via LOCC?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement

Why must every measure of entanglement satisfy the crucial property that its expected value is non-increasing under [LOCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LOCC)?

Comment: a standard reference is here [Chitambar et al. 2012](https://arxiv.org/abs/1210.4583)

Answer (score 5):

Because inherently, quantum entanglement is about non-classical correlations.

- Correlations can not be statistically introduced by acting on a part of the system only without knowing anything about the other part. That's why local quantum operations should not increase entanglement
- Classical correlations are the kind that could be introduced by classical mechanics, hence they can also be introduced by classical communication. So classical communication can increase correlations, but only classical ones and thus shouldn't increase entanglement.